# Matlab smooth a 3d mesh plot

Tags: matlab, smoothing

Hi I have a set of data A with each element corresponding to an x and y combination. When I plot this dat using mesh I get a graph with many spikes on it. This is not unnexpected but I would like a way to smooth these out to get a smooth surface.
I've tried to use the smooth3 command but cannot figure out how to make the suitable input.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

This is how my data is generated.

```
function v = f(x,y) % Not actual function
return x*rand()+y*rand()
end

x = 0.05:0.01:0.95;
y = 0.05:0.01:0.95;

o = zeros(length(x),length(y));
A = zeros(length(x), length(y));
for k = 1:5
    for i = 1:length(x)
        for j = 1:length(y)
            o(i,j) = f([x(i), y(j)]);
        end
    end
    A= A+o;
end
A = A/5;
```

This is what produces the plot.

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x);
mesh(A)
```

Comment: Your sample code does not run in its current form. `f` and `Average` are not defined in your code, `A` and `o` are not initialized.

Comment: I know, I stripped out most stuff to try and just show what the data will look like, f is a function returning a single number, Average = A, A and o are both innitialised to zeros(length(x),length(y)).

Comment: Then please put it in the code so those that attempt to help you won't have to bother with such things.

Comment: If you don't post the function that you're using, how can anyone reproduce your results and resolve your problem? By the way, `opt` is also undefined.

Comment: I can't post the actual function as it uses multiple executables some of which I don't have permission to redistribute. In any case the problem is not within the code example, but in how to smooth the output to a large smooth, probably quadratic surface.

Comment: Well then, you'll at least have to show the nature of the problem in order to proceed. Without any information, this question cannot be properly answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my be you can try a convolution of your variable A with a filter(the following is an example of a Gaussian filter).

> C = conv2(A,fspecial('gaussian', hsize, sigma));
>   check conv2 and fspecial in matlab help